# Tricky htaccess redirect using a wildcard for subfolder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I have a client request to rewrite the following, where "anything" can be any named directory:

```
https://clientdomain.com/anything/final-destination
```

to:

```
 https://clientdomain.com/final-destination
```

I know I can identify "anything" with the following [regex](https://regexr.com/6p7f9):

```
(?<=clientdomain.com\/)(.*)(?=final-destination)
```

...but how to incorporate that into a working rule eludes me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule without any lookahead:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(final-destination/?)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Here `[^/]+` matches 1 or more of any character that is not `/`.